# Formatting a multi-line Json user-input to a single line Json String to be passed to the JsonParser in a Java console app

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I am creating a console app that parses JSON and does something with it. However, I am having problems preparing the user's input to be passed to the JsonParser function:

```
final JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(userInputStr));
```

When the console prompts the user to enter valid JSON they are most likely going to be pasting formatted json that spans multiple lines.

I am trying to figure out how I can convert all of these lines into a space-free single string that can be passed to Json.createParser().

Small samples like this work if user enters it exactly as is below:

```
{"name":"Falco","age":3,"bitable":false,"certificate":null}
```

However, the following needs to be handled prior to passing to the JsonParser:

```
{
   "name":"Falco",
   "age":3,
   "bitable":false,
   "certificate":null
}
```

I started by trying the following to process each line from the user's input:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // use scanner.next() here...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is removing white space characters. So try `jsonStr.replaceAll("\\s+","")`

Comment: Only if there can't be any whitespace in the values - eg {"name":"Ricky Smith"} would lose the space in the name.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Have not thought about that. I'll update the answer when I get some ideas.